# PHP SDK -> Trying to pull album details from FB Page

Tags: facebook, sdk

I have a working script to pull details of all the albums in a Facebook Fan Page

I'm trying to get it pull details from the fan page with ID of 114696491979448
The output is blank. However, if I try with a different Fan Page - Such as 222984301060706 or 112605338840869 it works fine. This is my first time playing with any FB developing stuff.

Any ideas?
This is the code I've used..

Look here for code, can't work this code input out on this website
http://pastebin.com/AqachkBb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

The Facebook page was set to UK only, which meant the API couldn't access it either.
This is weird behaviour, but it worked nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve page albums I think you might have to authenticate yourself as the page before and get a different access token from the normal user token.
You can look on [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and scroll down to Page Login,  you'll be able to find out there how to retrieve the correct access token.

Comment: Ok, I've given my app permission to manage my pages, and it still not working :S

I got the long access token number but not sure what to do with it
The guide that I'm reading from http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/06/display-facebook-photos-to-your-website.html doesn't say anything about the long access token

Comment: Ahhhh FIXED IT
Because the page was restricted to UK visitors only, obviously facebook API is in US so that was causing the problem.. 

Thanks